# Formatting Issue With Navigation Bar + Page Tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css, formatting, uinavigationbar

I've been doing a school project, and I just ran into an issue. I got two different things from W3 - the sticky navigation bar, and the ability to have different tabs on a single page, such that all of the info can be presented in a less cluttered way. Problem is, when I try to incorporate the two at once, the tabs couldn't be moved from the very top unless I decided to insert a margin above them, which also moved the navigation bar. I think the problem is the fact that the navigation bar is sticky, so I can't move it, but I don't know why the tabs can't be any lower than the navigation bar.

```
Stack Overflow is yelling at me because it says I need code to insert a jsfiddle link, so here's my 'code.'
```

The fiddle can be accessed [here](https://jsfiddle.net/casuallysentient/ng9oxkh2/).

(Also, if anyone can figure out why the function that causes the text to appear isn't working, I'd appreciate that as well.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `top: 0px;` on the fixed `ul` and then you'll be able to add top margin to the `.tab` element without the navigation bar following. Also, your panels aren't showing because you aren't passing through the panel ID's.

Change this:

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Caesar')">Caesar</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Vigenere')">Vigenere</button>
```

to this:

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'caesartab')">Caesar</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'vigeneretab')">Vigenere</button>
```

It's not best practice to use inline JavaScript handlers (onclick) so try to avoid them if at all possible. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice) as to why.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a ton. :)